# SQL creating new columns from computed values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a question about sql. The problem states:

List part number, description, on_hand_Value (on_hand * price) of each part in class SG. Assign the name ON_HAND_VALUE to the computed coloumn

```
SELECT part_code, description,  ????
  FROM parts
  WHERE class = 'SG';
```

I dont know how to compute this new column from on_hand and price columns? Do I use `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this

```
SELECT part_code, description, on_hand * price As ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM parts
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    part_code, 
    description, 
    on_hand * price ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM parts
WHERE class = 'SG';
```

"AS" is optional, you may use or don't, in any case you will see "ON_HAND_VALUE" as a new column title